# java. Skype - send message

Tags: java, skype

I'm trying to understand how to work with Skype using java (JSkype lib)

i use example (official site):

```
package testproj;

import net.lamot.java.jskype.general.AbstractMessenger;
import net.lamot.java.jskype.general.MessageListenerInterface;
import net.lamot.java.jskype.windows.Messenger;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.util.Date;


public class JSkype implements MessageListenerInterface {

    private AbstractMessenger msgr = null;

   public JSkype() {

   msgr = new Messenger();
   msgr.addListener(this);
   msgr.initialize();
   try {
     Thread.sleep(5000);

     msgr.sendMessage("MESSAGE echo123 test message");

   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     new JSkype();
   }

   public void onMessageReceived(String str) {

     System.out.println("RESULT: "+str);
      }
}
```

after run, in console i have many information, but for me more intresting information, that I receive after send message:

```
RESULT: MESSAGE 21129 STATUS SENDING
RESULT: MESSAGE 21129 STATUS SENDING
RESULT: CHAT #my.name/$echo123;9797238991f90d78 ACTIVITY_TIMESTAMP 1294574640
```

and now I'm trying to understand, how to determine the success of sending a message?

yep, we need parsind result string.. but what is a number 21129? 9797238991f90d78? how i can know this number before start parsing?